# Count distinct calendar weeks, months in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, query-optimization

I already know how to count how many distinct days I have in my DB :

```
SELECT 
       COUNT(DISTINCT DATE (TIME)) AS distinct_days
FROM table;
```

But when I tried to count distinct weeks or months, the only solution I found is super-slow...

For months:

```
 SELECT 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME))) AS distinct_months
FROM table;
```

For weeks

```
SELECT 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME), EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIME))) AS distinct_weeks
FROM table;
```

Do you have any idea(s) to optimize ?

**(update) Notice:**

```
COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('week', time)) AS distinct_weeks
```

and

```
 COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME), EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIME))) AS distinct_weeks
```

don't have the same result (I want the second one) !

With `COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('week', time))` you have 53 possibilities, and with `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME), EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIME)))`, possibly an infinity (e.g. 2014-01 week 1 is different of 2013-01 week 1)...

Comment: Are you aware of this note from the manual: "*In the ISO definition, it is possible for early-January dates to be part of the 52nd or 53rd week of the previous year [...]  It's recommended to use the isoyear field together with week to get consistent results*"

Comment: I didn't know, thank you. But that doesn't solve my problem ?

Comment: To be honest: I don't understand what you are after. If neither `count(distinct extract(week from time))` nor the combination of year and week solves your problem, then you should post some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('week', time))` will return all the possible weeks in your sample, in opposition to `extract` that will only return 53. Where did you get that it only returns 53 weeks?

Comment: I want all possible CALENDAR weeks in my sample. Just for your info, I found this answer of my problem. I'm waiting 2 days to validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found something at least twice faster :

for distinct weeks:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct_weeks)
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME),EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIME)) AS distinct_weeks
      FROM table
      GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME),
               EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME),
               EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIME)) t
```

for distinct months:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct_months)
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME)) AS distinct_months
      FROM table
      GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME),
               EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME)) t
```

Comment: This is faster? Well, I would call this a flaw in Postgre. You can also try to `select count(*) from (select distinct EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME) FROM table)`. Maybe Postgre is faster on making distinct rows and counting them, than on counting distinct concatenated strings. I don't know, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: Your proposition is not faster, it's the same than the original one.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: the database is called Postgres (or PostgreSQL) but never *Postgre*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply truncating the date is faster, because you don't need string conversion and concatenation then:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('week', mytime)) AS distinct_weeks,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('month', mytime)) AS distinct_months,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('year', mytime)) AS distinct_years
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: No, you don't have all the different weeks. `COUNT(DISTINCT  DATE_TRUNC('week', time)) AS distinct_weeks` and `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME), EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIME))) AS distinct_weeks` don't have the same result !

Comment: Oops, I had years instead of weeks, as you could plainly see from the parameter and name. I'll edit.

Comment: That doesn't change the main problem of `date_trunc`. Look at my first post, I've added a notice.

Comment: Hm strange. So postgres treats weeks differently in EXTRACT and DATE_TRUNC obviously. The question arises which is righter :-) I'll try to check...

Comment: Yes because with `DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('week', time)` you have 53 possibilities, and with `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME), EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIME)))`, possibly an infinity (i.e 2014-01 week 1 is different of 2013-01 week 1)...

Comment: Ah, I see. DATE_TRUNC sees real weeks, such as 2014-12-31 and 2015-01-01 being in the same week, whereas your concatenation looks at a year's calandar weeks thus treating both dates as located in different (calendar) weeks. If this is a problem and you must stay with calandar weeks then you will have to stick to your concatenation. Truncation doesn't work then, because the calendar week is no natural week.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I still don't know how to optimize it. Thank you btw

Comment: You cannot, I think. You want to know the calendar week almost like ISO, but not really according to ISO. ISO treats 2016-01-01 as week 53/2015 and 2017-01-01 as week 52/2016. You don't. So you must build your week yourself - which you do by concatenating the ISO week number with the date's year and month. This costs extra.